# UI5 oData Service for two (or more) different backends

Tags: odata, sapui5, backend, sap-gateway

At the moment i still only have about 2 months of experience in UI5. i developed a little sample-app, used sap gateway builder to pass my requests to sap backend.

Now my employer asked me to research the possibility to access two different backends (one sap, one nonsap) via odata from the same app. After a little reading and thinking i came to the conclusion that it would be best to access both backends from a single gateway.

Since ive already worked with sap gateway, i wonder if there is a way to access nonsap backends with sap gateway? Are the better options?

Or is my current approach complete wrong and i should think about a whole other way?

Comment: You are correct, you can to that with a single gateway, reverse proxy or SAP WEB DISPACHER

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your approach and the non-sap-system:

Is the non-sap-system accesible via Webservices? Then use second data model (e.g. JSON/ODATA) within SAPUI5 by loading data via webservices after initial loadup of your application.

Is the non-sap-system connected to SAP? E.g. via RFC or another technology, then you can read data from the other system during calling your initial Gateway service and simply call your RFC function module in your method.

From my opinion you will not achieve an 'easy' way to read both via one single SAP NetWeaver Gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to access a non-SAP oData service via SAP Gateway. On the other hand you may want a router of some sort so that all services are exposed on the same network location and then incoming requests are routed to the appropriate backend for action.
You may also want to "mash-up" the SAP and non-SAP services into some sort of new service. In that case maybe look to some of the API management tools like Apigee to help you achieve that.